# Send Value in Send Button Click Event in Alert Control

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I wanted to create simple panic button in my application.This button will work in following manner:

> if user click on panic button one alert will be shown, in this alert
>   user will be provided pre-defined group to who he wanted to send
>   panic,

```
1) if user select committee group then user panic message will
   only sent to user who have role committee. 
2) if user select All then
   panic message will sent to all the member of application.
```

I don't know how could i send that particular value to button click event.Here groupList contains all my group name.
Here is my code,

```
     sendTextMessage() {

    let Groups: any = [];
    firebase.database().ref('panic_group').orderByKey().once('value', (items: any) => {

      items.forEach((item) => {
        Groups.push(item.val().Group_name);
        this.groupList = Groups;
      });

    let alertConfirm = this.alertCtrl.create();
    alertConfirm.setTitle('Choose Group');

    // Add the new group here!

    this.groupList.forEach(group => {
      alertConfirm.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: group,
            value: group.toLowerCase(),
            checked: group === group.toLowerCase()
        });
    });

    // ...
    alertConfirm.addButton({
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => {
              console.log("Cancel clicked");
            }
    });
    alertConfirm.addButton({
      text: 'Send',
          handler: () => {
            console.log("Send clicked");
           alert('cnt' + this.contacts);

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST", "https://control.msg91.com", true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            var settings = {
              "async": true,
              "crossDomain": true,
              "url": "http://api.msg91.com/api/v2/sendsms",
              "method": "POST",
              "headers": {
                "authkey": "198608A17R3Rqgwdh5a87f2ae",
                "content-type": "application/json"
              },
              "processData": false,
              "data": "{ \"sender\": \"SOCKET\", \"route\": \"4\", \"country\": \"91\", \"sms\": [ { \"message\": \"Panic Alert from Flat No " + this.flatNo + "\", \"to\": [ " + this.contacts + " ] }, { \"message\": \"Test Panic Alert from Flat No " + this.flatNo + "\", \"to\": [ " + this.contacts + " ] } ] }"


            }
            alert(settings.data);
            console.log(settings.data);
            jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
              alert('res' + response);
              alert("Sms Sent!");
            });
          }
     });

    alertConfirm.present();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this probelm by my own.

```
loadContacts(userGroup : string) {

 let contacts: any = [];

if(userGroup === 'Commitee Member'){

   var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
   ref.orderByChild("role").equalTo(userGroup).once("value", (items: any) => {

    items.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.val().contact_no != '0') {
        contacts.push({
          cnt:item.val().contact_no,
          flatNo:item.val().flatno
        });
      }
      this.contactList = contacts;

    });

    var length = this.contactList.length;

    if (length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

          this.contacts.push('<SMS TEXT=\"Panic  dynamic Alert for Commiittee members from Flat No '+this.contactList[i].flatNo + '\"><ADDRESS TO=\"'+this.contactList[i].cnt +'\"></ADDRESS></SMS>');
      }

      console.log("Formatted Contacts: ", this.contacts);
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
  });
}else{
  console.log(userGroup +"else");
  firebase.database().ref('users').orderByKey().once('value', (items: any) => {

    items.forEach((item) => {

      if (item.val().contact_no != '0') {
        contacts.push({
          cnt:item.val().contact_no,
          flatNo:item.val().flatno
        });
      }
      this.contactList = contacts;
    });

    var length = this.contactList.length;
    console.log(length);
    if (length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

         this.contacts.push('<SMS TEXT=\"Panic  dynamic Alert for All members from Flat No '+this.contactList[i].flatNo + '\"><ADDRESS TO=\"'+this.contactList[i].cnt +'\"></ADDRESS></SMS>');
      }

      console.log("Formatted Contacts: ", this.contacts);
    }
  },
    (error) => {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    });
}
```

}

```
alertConfirm.addButton({
  text: 'Send',
      handler:  data  => {
        console.log("Send clicked : "+data);
        this.loadContacts(data);
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "https://control.msg91.com", true);

        var settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": "https://control.msg91.com/api/postsms.php",
          "method": "POST",
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json"
          },
          "data": "<MESSAGE><AUTHKEY>******************</AUTHKEY><SENDER>SQatta</SENDER><ROUTE>4</ROUTE><CAMPAIGN>Panic Alert API</CAMPAIGN><COUNTRY>91</COUNTRY>"+ this.contacts + "</MESSAGE>"
        }

        jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          alert("Sms Sent!");
        });

      }
 });
```